# Regex matching when a keyword is present before OR after the subject

Tags: regex

I'm working on a bot that sits in our dev chat channel and listens for keywords and posts helpful links relevant to it.

Basically when the user says something like "Can I please get a review on `<storyid>`?" it will grab the relevant ticket and gitlab merge request links. But I want it to be intelligent enough to also trigger on something like "I have `<storyid>` that needs review." as well.

The closest I've got is

```
/review.*(US\d+)|(US\d+).*review/i
```

But this isn't ideal as it means I have to do extra checks to see if the match on the regex sits in the 1 or 2 position.

I also tried

```
/(?:review)?.*(US\d+).*(?:review)?/i
```

but this is effectively `/(US\d+)/i` which I don't want to trigger this type of response with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first make sure that `review` is in the string, then match the `US\d+`:

```
/^(?=.*review).*(US\d+)/i
```

The above match will fail if there is no `review`, due to the positive looahead.

If there is `review`, it will capture the `US\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that @Jerry's is more efficient (may be worth testing), but here is another way.  This looks behind for `review` and then `US\d+` OR `US\d+` looking ahead for `review`.

```
(?<=review).*?(US\d+)|(US\d+).*?(?=review)
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/kD6lT2)